# dd_belatedpng fix for IE6 on img tags

Tags: internet-explorer-6, pngfix, png-transparency, dd-belatedpng

I used the Drew Diller DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a.js script to fix IE6 transparency with png, actually It seems to work fine except for pictures within img tags. For imgs tags it solve the transparency but makes the png file look bigger and out of box. I guess the script doesn't apply the css rules specified for IE6 as shown down below in the IE.css file , the file seems to keep its original size instead of width:171px; height:81px. Any idea how I can fix this? And I would not like to replace the img tags because the website I'm working on has a thousand of them.

```
  <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company" title="Company" width="215" /></a></div>

    /*styles.css*/

        #logo {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:200px;
            height:50px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }

/*IE.css*/
html.ltie7 #logo img { display:block;width:171px; height:81px; margin-left:20px;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of is to resize the actual image.  It's also good practice to display images at their actual size, for visual quality and performance.